# Kafka to zookeeper command produces error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic activityTopic --zookeeper localhost:2181/kafka --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1
```

The above command from kafka produces an error

```
Error while executing topic command   org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode =  NoNode for /brokers/ids
 org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkNoNodeException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode =   NoNode for /brokers/ids
at org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkException.create(ZkException.java:47)
at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.retryUntilConnected(ZkClient.java:685)
at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.getChildren(ZkClient.java:413)
at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.getChildren(ZkClient.java:409)
at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.getChildren(ZkUtils.scala:462)
at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.getSortedBrokerList(ZkUtils.scala:78)
at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.createTopic(AdminUtils.scala:170)
at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.createTopic(TopicCommand.scala:93)
at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:55)
at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers/ids
at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:111)
at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getChildren(ZooKeeper.java:1472)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getChildren(ZooKeeper.java:1500)
at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkConnection.getChildren(ZkConnection.java:99)
at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient$2.call(ZkClient.java:416)
at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient$2.call(ZkClient.java:413)
at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.retryUntilConnected(ZkClient.java:675)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps Zookeeper wasn't started?

Comment: i'm not familiar with how kafka uses zk, but this looks like the kafka system wasn't started with the same zk connection information.

Comment: try removing the ```/kafka```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case, the problem was that **I was specifying a non-existent kafka chroot.**

I discovered that our company ops team had configured the kafka chroot as `purple-elephants`, and configured the creation of this chroot to be ensured on kafka service restart.

First I issued a `sudo service kafka restart` and the log shows that the chroot was created:

```
Ensuring chroot '/purple-elephants' exists
Starting Kafka server.
```

Then I simply issued:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic activityTopic --zookeeper localhost:2181/purple-elephants --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1
```

Answer (score 4):

In a nutshell, this means that the `kafka-topics.sh` script cannot find any active Kafka brokers registered with ZooKeeper. This could be for several reasons:

1. Your Kafka broker(s) are not running.
2. Your Kafka broker(s) are up, but they're connected to a different ZooKeeper instance than the one you referenced in your `kafka-topics.sh` command.
3. Your Kafka broker(s) are up, and connecting to the correct ZooKeeper instance, but they're registered under a different chroot than the one in your command. In your example of `--zookeeper localhost:2181/kafka`, the chroot is the `/kafka` bit. You can find the chroot being used by your Kafka brokers in the `$KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties` file, under the `zookeeper.connect` property.

Answer (score 1):

while creating topic, it should be zookeeper url with --zookeeper option. 
It should work the following line if zookeeper & kafka are working.

```
--zookeeper localhost:2181
```

[This link describes how to create a topic.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_kafka/apache_kafka_quick_guide.htm)
You can also check the no of available ids in zookeeper cli. `./zkCli.sh` & then `ls /brokers/ids` . At lease one broker id should be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing /kafka as the command is

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 3 --topic Falcon
```

If it still occurs then be sure about the path in zookeeper.properties of

```
dataDir(default is /tmp/zookeeper)
```

and path in server.properties of

```
log.dirs(default is /tmp/kafka-logs)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have started only zookeeper and forgot starting kafka server. I started the kafka server as well and then created the topic. The command worked fine.